# Decode dynamically received output as JWT is not working in Swift 3. "The Token is not yet valid (not before claim)"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, jwt, decode

i get token form HTTP request in `JWT` format. if i print and decode my output as static value it's works fine but when i tried to decode output value, it's doesn't work and show error message

> The Token is not yet valid (not before claim).

here is my code

```
if let token = parseResult["token"] as? String{
    //print(token)
    do {
        let claims = try JWT.decode(token, algorithm: .hs256(Constants.Route.Secret.data(using: .utf8)!))
            print("\(claims)")                       
    } catch {
            print("\(error)")
            return
    }
}
```

if i use my printed token above for next request, it's works fine. i don't know it's error in [`JWT` decoder](https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift) or in my `JSONSerialization` method. but data printed from `JSONSerialization` is working if i use like this :

```
if let token = parseResult["token"] as? String{
  let testToken:String = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ"
    do {
        let claims = try JWT.decode(testToken, algorithm: .hs256(Constants.Route.Secret.data(using: .utf8)!))
            print("\(claims)")                       
    } catch {
            print("\(error)")
            return
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely ["nbf" claim](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.5) is not valid yet.

Comment: Can you add *actual* JWT token you have problem with? First two parts will be enough.

Comment: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

Comment: Well, this token has no "nbf", and no date claims at all. So if it's actual token  you're having problem with, the error must be in `JWT` library you're using. Can you add info about it to the question (name, repository, cocoapod)?

Comment: a) **edit it in question itself**, b) it should be link to the original library, not clone in your project, if i understand correctly lib is [JSONWebToken](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JSONWebToken).

Comment: JSON Web Token Swift: https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift this is the JWT repository i'm using

Comment: It is generally not good practice to decode the JWT client side, what do you need to do with the claims client side that you can't do by virtue of passing data back from your server side application?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out that JSONWebToken was not working properly. 
now i have implemented [JWTDecode](https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift) and its start decoding received JWT properly. i don't know why but JSONWebToken have some serious bug for for SWIFT 3.